# Can i use a Subject to make a custom async validator?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation, angular-observable

Is there any chance that i can achieve this with a subject? for the time being i have only acheived this with a Promise. so i call the resolve method and that works correct.

i was trying to do the following.

```
forbiddenEmail(control: FormControl): Observable<any> {

    const obs = new Subject();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (control.value === 'test@test.com') {
        obs.next({'emailIsForbidden': true});
      } else {
        obs.next(null);
      }
    }, 2000);
    return obs;
  }
```

Here, im trying to emit the event whenever the value is test@test.com, otherwise null as the docs in Angular say about the validators.
im trying to simulate lets say a backend service thats why i implement setTimeout fucntion and give a timeout of 2 secs.
Now the problem is that when i inspect the input element which i place the validator (an email input element) then class `ng-pending` is displayed always.
so, for some reason im not subscribing to it i know that. but how i could?

this is where i call the validator inside the FormGroup.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = new FormGroup({
      'userData': new FormGroup({
        'username': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.forbiddenNames.bind(this)]),
        'email': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.email], this.forbiddenEmail.bind(this))
      }),
      'gender': new FormControl('male'),
      'hobbies': new FormArray([])
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete your observable:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (control.value === 'test@test.com') {
    obs.next({'emailIsForbidden': true});
  } else {
    obs.next(null);
  }
  obs.complete();
}, 2000);
```

But this could be defined in a much simpler way:

```
forbiddenEmail2(control: FormControl): Observable<any> {
  const result = control.value === 'test@test.com' ? {'emailIsForbidden': true} : null;
  return Observable.of(result).delay(2000);
}
```

This is also more correct, since it actually validates the input as it is at the moment the validator is invoked, instead of validating the input as it is 2 seconds later. In a more realistic use-case: you would get the input immediately, and send it to the backend.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/qAdl7lTaKzn0bUNOp8fy?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot. Funny thing is that the 2nd way didn;t work for me for some reason. although it works in the demo. it just stucks on pending again. but im happy i got that with the Subject. i guess the problem was that Subject need to unsubscribe and thats complete does?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation you can achieve that with returning observable: 
https://angular.io/api/forms/AsyncValidatorFn

I tried to prove it with sample of code but it looks like it doesn't work as it should...

It looks like angular problem itself, here it's reported: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13200

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, just return the subject with `asObservable()`:

```
forbiddenEmail(control: FormControl): Observable<any> {
  const subject = new Subject();

  setTimeout(() => {
    if (control.value === 'test@test.com') {
      subject.next({ emailIsForbidden: true });
    } else {
      subject.next(null);
    }
  }, 2000);

  return subject.asObservable();
}
```